# python errno 23 - socket livestatus

Tags: python, sockets, errno

I'm trying to send two queries to the server with this script, to get the [MK Livestatus](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html):

live.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
socket_path = "/tmp/run/live"
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(socket_path)

# Get Hosts
hosts = s.send("GET hosts\nColumns: name\n")
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
hosts = s.recv(1024)
hosts = [ line.split(';') for line in hosts.split('\n')[:-1] ]

hostsB = s.send("GET hosts\nColumns: name\n")

s.close()
```

But I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "live.py", line 13, in
>    hostsB = s.send("GET hosts\nColumns: name\n") socket.error:
>   [Errno 32] Broken pipe

I think the error is related to the command "s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)". But the author says, that this is [required](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html#H1:Using%20Livestatus). You will get no answer (timeout?), if you remove this line.

How can I send two queries?

---

### ***SOLUTION***

so ... I've written a function that does the job :-)

**Function**

```
def sendQuery(query):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(socket_path)
    s.send(query)
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

    answer = ''
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        answer += data
        if len(data) < 1024:
            break

    s.close()
    return answer
```

**Usage**

```
sendQuery("GET hosts\nColumns: name\n")
```

Comment: So you close your socket for writing, and then you write to it? How do you expect that to work?

Comment: By the way, considering that the example code you show is less than 20 lines, which line corresponds to line 21 in your actual code? Can you please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and have that in your question, together with the actual error from *that* program?

Comment: I don't want to close the socket - The command "s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)" is needed before you can receive the answer. But I need more than one query. Eg. line 50 one query and the answer and eg. line 70 another query and the answer.

Comment: *Why* do you need to shutdown writing to receive answers? You do know that sockets are two-way and full duplex (i.e. it can both send and receive at the same time).

Comment: You can run this example now. WR doesn't mean "writing" > "If how is SHUT_WR, further sends are disallowed" -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

Comment: When the reference says "further sends are disallowed" that means that *you* can't send/transmit/*write* any more to the socket. You don't need it to receive/read data from the socket. And what do you think the abbreviation `WR` stands for, if not writing?

Comment: Do you know a working solution to send two queries?

Comment: Yes, don't do the `shutdown` call.

Comment: "You will get no answer (timeout?), if you remove this line." > I can't remove this line ;)

Comment: Where have you read that? It's not in the link you provided, but it does say "Close sending direction. That way the other side ***knows we are finished***." (emphasis mine). Since you are not finished, you can't do the half-close.

Comment: And then I say that it's not, ***unless*** the server have special handling for it. So I think you need to look at the server as well.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so ... I've written a function that does the job :-)

**Function**

```
def sendQuery(query):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(socket_path)
    s.send(query)
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

    answer = ''
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        answer += data
        if len(data) < 1024:
            break

    s.close()
    return answer
```

**Usage**

```
sendQuery("GET hosts\nColumns: name\n")
```

Comment: This code did not work all the time for me. I had to change the line 'if len(data) < 1024:' into 'if len(data) < 1:' .  It might be because of python3 or a loaded checkmk server. And i also used  return answer.decode('utf-8') because i needed a string instead of bytearray.