# mk livestatus LQL: Select Nagoios service both in CRITICAL and Hard state

Tags: nagios

Following example script can pick out CRITICAL service but it also will select CRITICAL service in both SOFT and HARD state. I read though R1 doc many times. Still failed to select service in HARD and CRITICAL state.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
socket_path = '/var/spool/nagios/cmd/livestatus'
def sendQuery(query):
    """
    INPUT: LQL string.
    OUPUT: query result in string.
    REF  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730883/python-errno-23-socket-livestatus
    """
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(socket_path)
    s.send(query)
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

    answer = ''
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        answer += data
        if len(data) < 1024:
            break
    s.close()
    return answer

LQL = 'GET services\n' + \
      'Columns: host_name description state last_state_change last_time_critical\n' + \
      'Filter: scheduled_downtime_depth = 0 \n'     + \
      'Filter: host_scheduled_downtime_depth = 0\n' + \
      'Filter: in_notification_period = 1\n'        + \
      'Filter: state    = 2 \n'

print sendQuery(LQL)
```

R1: https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html

Comment: "will select CRITICAL service in both SOFT and HARD state" -> "will select "CRITICAL service in both SOFT OR HARD state"

Comment: What's your question?  What are you expecting the code to do?

Comment: state = 2 will report CRITCAL(2) services that are both in SOFT and HARD status(state). Question: Is it possible to report alert are in both CRITICAL and HARD state ? I tried adding another filter like "Filter: hard_state =1" but it won't work. Looks like hard_state column only avaiable in "host" table, not in "service" table.

Comment: You should be able to assume a 'soft state' as long as the value for 'current_attempt' is less than the value of 'max_attempts'.  Also, what is the value of 'current_state', is that readable?

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for help. See the solution at http://lists.mathias-kettner.de/pipermail/checkmk-en/2016-January/018483.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided by livestatus community, See R1.

select_type = 1 where 1 = HARD service alert. 0 = SOFT.

R1: http://lists.mathias-kettner.de/pipermail/checkmk-en/2016-January/018483.html